# Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: string, powershell

I have a simple script that reads a file, calculates data, and outputs a different file.  The file will change on a day to day basis.  I'm using the syntax:

```
Get-Content 'C:\',$date,'_FinalResults.txt'
```

but I am receiving the following error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument...
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place `$date` is a [sub expression `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) and enclose the string literal with double quotes, the variable  will be expanded as you want:

```powershell
Get-Content "C:\$($date)_FinalResults.txt"
```

See a demonstration below:

```powershell
PS > $date = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd") 
PS > "C:\$($date)_FinalResults.txt"
C:\20140625_FinalResults.txt

PS >
```

Comment: Hi iCodez.  I'm using a similar approach to the $date syntax, `$date = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")`.  However, using the same approach you had listed, I'm receiving this error: : `ObjectNotFound: (C:\...inalResults.txt:String)`